# Send spacebar key in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i am try to send spacebar key in wpf C# i try SendKeys.SendWait(" "); and SendKeys.SendWait("{spacebar}"); it's not work and the Send method will not work in wpf what is the way to do that , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution i should use 3rd party library https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ it's work in WPF